# OOP - inheritance [Java]

Tags: java, oop, inheritance

**bb** refers Derived  class, when i call **show()** method,  but when i print **bb.b**  - is prints Base class property . 
Why is this happening?

```
class Base {
    int b=10;
    public void show() {

        System.out.println("Base show() called");

    }
}



class Derived extends Base {

    int b=20;
    public void show() {

        System.out.println("Derived show() called");

    }

}

public class MainClass {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Base bb = new Derived();;

        bb.show();
        System.out.println(bb.b);

    }

}
```

output :

Derived show() called

10

Comment: Overriding only exists for methods.

Comment: No, it's not.It's hiding.

Comment: It's not overriding. In that case you're using a `Derived` variable to print a `Derived` field.

Answer (score 2):

While you declare your variable as a `Base` obj (i.e. `Base bb = new Derived();`), that does not mean your `b` object is no longer an instance of `Derived` (verify this with `b instanceof Derived`).

This is called hiding and is similar to what people usually do when declaring variables that might later change implementation for example `private List<String> someList = new ArrayList<>();`. In more technical terms: it's a way of decoupling your code from a specific implementation.

As to why `b` is 10 (the `Base` class's value) and not 20: that is because you are explicitly referring to `b` value in `Base` class (as mentioned by Timothy Truckle's answer). If you were to explicitly cast your `b` object back to `Derived` type, you will see 20 being printed instead:

```
System.out.println(((Derived)b).b);
```

Answer (score 0):

You output is `10`because you explicitly access variable `b` in class `Base`.

Beside the technical aspect doing so this is **not** OOP since it violates the most important OO principle: *information hiding / encapsulation*.

Answer (score 0):

There is no polymorphism for fields in Java.

Variables are resolved compile-time, methods run-time. so always Base Class variables (not child’s inherited variables) will be accessed.

So whenever upcasting happens always remember

1. Base Class variables will be accessed.
2. Sub Class methods(overridden methods if overriding happened else inherited methods as it is from parent) will be called.

Answer (score 0):

This is because the compiler implements special run time polymorphism for methods only. This is also called method overriding.

For variables, the value will always be from the Base class, because that is the type of bb object regardless of the class with with it is instantiated.